# Play Bootstrap carousel when Modal closes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, carousel

I have managed to source the code for pausing the carousel when modal is opened, but it stays paused when modal is closed.

I have researched for this, but cant seem to find a working fix.

Thank you in advance.

Pause

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal',function (e) {
    $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
})
```

I have tried different variations, but my knowledge of JS is not that great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hide.bs.modal` event.

```
$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal',function (e) {
   $('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
})
```

Comment: Works now, had a few issues but turns out i missed a bracket.  thank you